# foreach not working on list of QPair

Tags: qt

Using Qt, I want this code to work:

```
QList<QPair<QString, QString>> list;
foreach (QPair<QString, QString> pair, list)
{
}
```

instead, I get the error:

> 'pair' : undeclared identifier

Using a `typedef` I can make it work, but this is not what I want (unless this is the only thing that works):

```
typedef QPair<QString, QString> MyPair;
QList<MyPair> list;
foreach (MyPair pair, list)
{
}
```

Can anyone explain why the first foreach doesn't compile?

Comment: And what you want? Maybe you need foreach( MyPair **&** pair, list ) {}

Btw. foreach - is macros, so using of comma inside is not acceptable. typedef - is only solution.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov: I want to use the `foreach` like in any other case: f.e. `QList<QString> list; foreach (QString str, list) {}`

Comment: You should declare `pair` outside your loop : `QPair<QString, QString> pair; foreach( pair, list) {}`.

Comment: Sure - http://stackoverflow.com/a/16104822/1035613 :)

Comment: This is explained in the documentation: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/containers.html#the-foreach-keyword

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not possible to use template classes inside qt foreach statement which contains more than one template parameter, because comma separator conflicts with comma separator inside macros.

```
#define add( a, b ) (a + b)

template < typename T1, typename T2 >
struct DATA
{
  static const T1 val1 = 1;
  static const T2 val2 = 2;
};

// Usage
const int c = add( 1, 2 ); // OK
const int d = add( DATA< int, int >::val1 , DATA< int, int >::val2 ); // FAIL
```

because macros add will interpret "DATA< int" as first argument, and " int >::val1" as second, and so on.

Comment: QPair<QString,QString> pair;
    foreach(pair,tmplist) mainlist.append(pair);

Comment: Yep, already provided - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104192/foreach-not-working-on-list-of-qpair/16104594?noredirect=1#comment22996614_16104192

Answer (score 14):

it's not the foreach error. It's declaration error. You declared list like this:

```
QList<QPair<QString, QString>> list;
```

while it should this way:

```
QList<QPair<QString, QString> > list;
```

Just declare QPair outside of loop:

```
QPair<QString,QString> pair;
foreach(pair,list){

}
```

Comment: It make difference for some usecases when >> may be interpreted like operator>> overloading instead of template brackets.

Comment: the other way `>>` will be treated as `>>` operator

Comment: Anyway, this post is useless. Original error described in my answer below.

Comment: @Dmitry Sazanov Is that so? For me your answer seems useless and misleading, as i am easily using right now foreach

Comment: Ofc, your post is not useless, but it is not related to original question. If you not agree - please, edit your answer and provide workable code with foreach statement, that requested by topic starter.

Comment: already did that, works just fine. And even before edit it vas related, because in this case `>>` is not right

Comment: Error was in comma ;), not in >>

Comment: compiler probably would not even get to coma if it is declared with `>>` since list would be undefined, wrong declaration

Comment: the `>>` is perfectly valid in C++11

Comment: valid only in c++11, sounds very flexible and portable (sarcasm)

Answer (score 0):

Some explanation with above answer... if your compiler accept

```
 QList<QPair<QString, QString>> list;
```

giving no error on such declaration, reasons for topic caster error is different and indeed has to do with a fact that declaration must be done outside of foreach() loop. That's explained in QT documentation.

regarding >> and > >... that's old story and latest GCC (so linux/mac) consider it to be a syntax mistake, because it's not conforming standard. >> in GCC manner is treated as operator with all follow-up errors..